# How to Convert UInt8 to Anyobject in Swift 2.3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, type-conversion

I am trying in CryptoSwift and i tried to UInt8 to Anyobject .

How to Convert this

let encrypted:[UInt8]!

```
        encrypted = try AES(key: value, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).encrypt(myArray)

    let mynObject:AnyObject = encrypted as! AnyObject
```

Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Array>' (0x11a6062e8) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x119d3d018).

Anyone help really Appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @vadian: i update the question

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: See [AES encryption in CBC mode](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/7026/aes-encryption/23676/aes-encryption-in-cbc-mode-with-a-random-iv-swift-2-3#t=20161018125703666645) in SO Documentation for example code..

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
let anInt:UInt8 = 20
let anObject:AnyObject = anInt as AnyObject
```

The key part you want to pay attention to is `anInt as AnyObject` this is how you convert a Uint8 to AnyObject.

Comment: why do you need the `as!` here? this upcast will always succeed.

Comment: Thanks ,i update the question.Could you help in this

Comment: because the OP did not upload his code and this is safer if the variable does not have a type. but now I know it does Ive removed the !. thanks :)